# Textmate2 - How to put spaces between curly brace { } by default

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundle, curly-braces, textmate2

I'm developing **Ruby on Rails** application in **Textmate2**. I have to use a lot of curly braces `{}` syntax in Rails coding.

By default, when I type opening curly brace `{` , then `{}` is automatically displayed. In most Rails tutorial, it is so conventional to put **spaces** between curly braces at the start and end positions. For e.g.,

```
{ name: "aaa", email: "aaa@gmail.com" } # hash example
it { should have_selector('p', 'some text') } # rspec example
```

It's a little tiring to put **spaces** by hand in every coding sentences.
I want to put **spaces** between curly braces automatically. I mean when I type `{` , I want `{  }` to be appeared by default.

I don't know which bundles do I need to modify. Please show me ways how to be get done this syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this you'll need to create your own snippet:

Open the `Bundle Editor` and select `Ruby` from the list. Press `Command` + `n` to create a new item, select `Snippet` from the drop down.

Name your new `Snippet` something appropriate, "Spaced Curly Braces" perhaps. The snippet editor should contain only:

```
{ $0 }
```

Click, in the `Bundle Editor` drawer, on `Key Equivalent` to bind the snippet to a key, in this case use `{`

This will cause this snippet to exist everywhere in TextMate, to limit it to only working in Ruby change the `Scope Selector` to `source.ruby`, or for the Ruby on Rails people: `text.html.erb.rails, source.ruby.rails, source.ruby.rails.embedded.html, meta.rails.helper, meta.rails.unit_test, meta.rails.controller, meta.rails.functional_test, text.haml, source.ruby.rspec`

Comment: Firstly, I respect your effort. I tested it, this solution works. For Ruby on Rails guys, you can add "text.html.erb.rails, source.ruby.rails, source.ruby.rails.embedded.html, meta.rails.helper, meta.rails.unit_test, meta.rails.controller, meta.rails.functional_test, text.haml, source.ruby.rspec" to the Scope Selector.